# ListView id field does not take into account and produce error

Tags: android-studio

I have such declaration of ListView:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

I have already set the ListView's `id` field a `@id/android:list`, but rather than I got the error `Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'`.

Comment: Could you show some details? Show us full xml where you declare ListView and code that are using this component. Also it is helpfull to get full error text.

Answer (score 0):

This is totally wrong my friend.

In `android:id` property you need to define your own id for widget. So if you want to give id as list then it would be like:

```
android:id="@+id/list"
```

The android:list will point to the variable having id as list in android libraries.

Answer (score 0):

The id you are giving is not correct.

Use : `android:id="@+id/listView"`

When you create a new view, you should use + for giving an id.

Comment: I have one more question That i want to make an Application which work Only on Samsung android device. So what should i have to do?